# How do i output a javascript template literal to the console

Tags: javascript, string, template-literals

```
var variable = 2;

var x = `${variable}`;
console.log(x) to output `${variable}`
```

not 2
thank you. am new to programming

Comment: You mean like ``console.log("`${variable}`")``? Have you read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)?

Comment: By the time `x` is assigned the replacements have already been made within the template literal and `x` only contains the result. You can't retrieve the template literal from the assigned variable (just as you can't retrieve a function from its return value)

Answer (score -1):

You can escape the backticks:

```js
var variable = 2;

var x = `\`${variable}\``;
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to Programming. Depending on the overall goal here, I would maybe set another variable, say y to the string of the template literal.

```
var y = '`${variable}`'
```

Unfortunately, Javascript will always evaluate the value stored in a variable storing a primitive data type like a string or number.